# I tried to map function yet throw error (Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.)

Tags: redux

Warning: Each child[enter image description here][1] in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAfvR.png

please help me regarding this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `key` has to be on the outermost element, which in this case is `<>`.

So rewrite `<>` to `<React.Fragment>` and then add a `key` prop.

```js
<React.Fragment key={id.id}>
...
</React.Fragment>
```

And please share source code, not screenshots in future questions.

Comment: ok Thanku so much sir, and ahead i will share my source code